# Babel : error when trying to use relay preset 'Couldn't find preset "relay" relative to directory'

Tags: babeljs, relayjs, relay

I'm trying to install `relay` in my project using the official docs.

I installed relay using:

```
yarn add react react-dom react-relay
yarn add --dev babel-plugin-relay graphql
```

My `.babelrc` file looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "relay", "env", "react"
  ]
}
```

When running webpack go this error:

```
ERROR in ./js/app.js
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "relay" relative to directory "/Users/nicolas/projects/grocery_umbrella/apps/grocery_web/assets"
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`babel-plugin-relay` is a plugin, not a preset, so you need

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env", "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "relay"
  ]
}
```